# How to convert a string to an array of string arrays kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, type-conversion, arrayofarrays

I have such a string

```
val text = "[[\"1\", \"Steffan\", \"Hibbert\"], [\"2\", \"Shaunie\", \"Barry\"]]"
```

How to parse it.
Is there any library?
Or maybe I need to manually

Comment: @Tenfour04 this looks like standard JSON. not a custom format

Comment: You're right. I was thrown off by the escaping.